# What does drinking worm blood do?

Tags: noita

Drinking worm blood doesn't seem to harm me, drench me or anything else except the screen starts pulsing. Is there some hidden effect to the worm blood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the wiki article on worms](https://noita.gamepedia.com/Worm),

> Worms bleed worm blood, which when drank grants temporary night vision that is necessary to see in the Dark Cave, as well as a colour shifting screen effect.

Comment: I also heard rumors about it increasing kick strength.

Comment: It also works in the Magic Temple.